# F is the group of additive functions, K is the subgroup of constant functions, find a subgroup $H \simeq F/K$

Tags: abstract-algebra

F is the group of additive functions, K is the subgroup of constant functions, find a subgroup $H \simeq F/K$

I need some help understanding this. I know you can say $H = \{ h \in F\,| \,h(0) = 0\}$ and this will be isomorphic to $F/K$ but I don't really understand why.

First, I'm having trouble seeing that $H$ is a subgroup of $F$

Comment: What is an additive function to you? According to the definition I'd assume, that is $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ a constant function is hardly ever additive. Maybe affine function?

Comment: okay that helps a bit more. so H is closed $f(0+0) = f(0) + f(0) = 0$, $e(0) = 0$ and each $f \in H$ will be it's own inverse

Comment: I am sorry I do not understand at all what you are trying to do.

Comment: Trying to show H is isomorphic to F/K where K is the subgroup of F of all constant functions and F is the group of all additive functions.